# Is there a way to query on Type using System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have class "A" which has a collection of class "B". "D" is a subclass of "B" with the property "DMatter" (not inherited from "B")

I can select "A"s that have a "D" with certain content like this with regular Linq:

```
 var result = 
    Aset.Where(a => a.Bs.OfType<D>().Any(d => d.DMatter.Contains("ii"))); //works!
```

I can dynamically on B's properties like so:

```
 var result = Aset.Where("Bs.Any(BStuff.Contains(\"bb\"))");//works!
```

But I can't find a way to something like this:

```
result = Aset.Where("Bs.OfType<D>().Any(DMatter.Contains(\"ii\"))");//Explodes!
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Clarify that "Explodes!" thing

Comment: @wudzik: It gives an exception: ParseException>>No property or field 'OfType' exists in type 'List`1'
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance)

Comment: Looking through the code of `System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser`, it seems that there is not `OfType` parsing implemented unfortunately. Refer [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbfa7e59-e97f-4d34-9810-5dbf6b8f444c/dynamic-linq-expression-for-oftype-and-sum?forum=linqtosql) about it.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: Do you have any suggestions or experience with tools for building Linq from strings. All I have been able to find so far is pretty limited.

Comment: Unfortunately, Dynamic LINQ is the best I know...

Comment: @KonradKokosa: If you make your remark an answer, I can award you the point due. "No you can not" appears to be the valid answer in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the code of `System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser`, it seems that there is no `OfType` parsing implemented unfortunately. Refer [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbfa7e59-e97f-4d34-9810-5dbf6b8f444c/dynamic-linq-expression-for-oftype-and-sum?forum=linqtosql) about it, where workaround is provided as `IQueryable` extension methods. It seems it is the most you can get without deep dive into `System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser` source.

```
public static class MyQueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable OfType(this IQueryable source, string typeStr)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (typeStr == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("typeStr");
        }

        Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(typeStr);
        MethodInfo methodOfType = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "OfType" && m.IsGenericMethod);

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(null, methodOfType.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type }), new Expression[] { source.Expression }));
    }
}
```

and then you can:

```
var result = someList.OfType("SomeNamespace.SomeClass");
```

Answer (score 2):

This functionality (`Cast` and `OfType`) is now implemented in [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).

See the api documentation: [OfType](https://stefh.github.io/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/html/50e96fe4-c3ee-d8ac-06eb-d57b9728b4ea.htm)